# Using VBA to reference a cell in another sheet which itself is referenced by its text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I am new at VBA and am attempting to create a product which is a budgeting tool. I am trying to loop through a range of cells which starts on D2 and goes down until there is a break in the cells which contain data. This has to run for every sheet after sheet 4. With each cell in D after D2, it references back to a Sheet in my document called "Master Trainings". Then I need a formula to be automatically inputted into the text box to the right of the training course (in column D on the pages after 4). This formula is `"=B9*'Master Trainings!'XX"` where XX is the cell to the right of the training course of the same name on the Master Trainings sheet. If you can get the loop to run down, great, but I am trying to get it to actually input the formula first off. I have tried using quotes to put it in manually and concatenate with the value on the Master Trainings I am trying to find, but it is not working. This is what I have so far after trying it out again.

```
Dim findRng As Range
Dim foundRng As Range
Set findRng = Sheets("Master Trainings").Range("A:A")
Set foundRng = findRng.Find(Range("D2").Value)
Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("E2").Formula = "=" & Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("B9") & "*" & foundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was able to work for me. I am specifying C1 as a Variant just so debugging was easier. It is a cell after the 7th line of code with the address of the row and column+1 of the text that I wanted (i.e. it is looking one cell to the right in the same row). Then I specify the range and the formula inside with C1 being the cell I wanted in the formula.

```
Sheets(TextBox1.Value).Select
Dim findRng As Range
Dim foundRng As Range
Set findRng = Sheets("Master Trainings").Range("A:A")
Set foundRng = findRng.Find(Range("D2").Value)
Dim C1 As Variant
C1 = Cells(foundRng.Row, foundRng.Column + 1).Address(0, 0)
Range("E2").Formula = "=B9*'Master Trainings'!" & C1
```

Answer (score 0):

edited: swapped `'` and `!` in `"=B9*'Master Trainings!'"`

Try this:

```
Worksheets(TextBox1.Value).Range("E2").Formula = "=B9*'Master Trainings'!" & foundRng.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False)
```

Comment: This also didn't work. It gave me a runtime error '1004'. Maybe it has to do with what I defined as the range variables above? I have used this technique to quickly search through a single column or row before and find a certain piece of cell data, so I am not sure if that is causing the problem here, and if it is, how so.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what I was doing wrong. I believe that foundRng, even though it is set as a Range, it returns the data which is inside that range. For what I was doing, it kept returning a string of whatever was inside, rather than the cell name or even the cell itself. Using .Row and.Column should allow me to actually get the position of the cell and use that in my code. I will post updates as they come.

Comment: @alcopo63q: see edited answer (there was a typo). While as for the `Range` return type, please note that its _default_ property is `Value` hence if you use `some variable = foundRng` (ore the likes) and `somevariable` is compatible with the `Value` of `foundRng`, you get that value. While if you explicitly use a different property of a `Range` variable, then you get it (e.g.: `MsgBox foundRng.Address`)

Comment: Ah okay, I get it now. This has seemed to work fine (barring the typo), and is working well. I literally started using VBA a little over a week ago so this was helpful. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. And if my code answered your question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: @alcopo63q, I'd appreciate your accepting my answer as the solution. thank you

Comment: Your answer was a good start, but didn't actually fix the problem as it did not return the value of the cell as a string which was necessary to input the text inside the formula seen. This is why I separately used Cells to change it to a string as to work with inputting the code.

Comment: I don't get you: `foundRng.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False)` returns a string